# Loading BMP into byte array using JavaFX

Tags: javafx, bitmap

I am trying to create a simple Bitmap class using JavaFX which allows me to load, use, modify and save a bitmap to file (for a scientific simulator). I have problem loading the image into a byte array.

1- Am I correct that each pixel will need 3 bytes space in the buffer?

2- getPixels function receives the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class javafx.scene.image.PixelFormat$ByteRgb cannot be cast to class javafx.scene.image.WritablePixelFormat (javafx.scene.image.PixelFormat$ByteRgb and javafx.scene.image.WritablePixelFormat are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

The cast to (WritablePixelFormat) was suggested by Intellij. What am I doing wrong?

3- How can I use getPixels function to load the whole image into a 2D array of RGB integers? (to make  working with pixels easier)

Thanks.

```
public class BMP
{
    byte[] buffer;
    int width;
    int height;

    public BMP()
    {
    }

    public void load(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        //Creating an image
        Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream(filename));
        this.width = (int)image.getWidth();
        this.height = (int)image.getHeight();
        this.buffer = new byte[width * height * 3];

        //Reading color from the loaded image
        PixelReader pixelReader = image.getPixelReader();

        //Reading pixels of the image
        /*
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                //Retrieving the color of the pixel of the loaded image
                Color color = pixelReader.getColor(x, y);
                System.out.println(color.toString());
            }
        }*/

        pixelReader.getPixels(
                0,
                0,
                width,
                height,
                (WritablePixelFormat<ByteBuffer>) PixelFormat.getByteRgbInstance(),
                buffer,
                0,
                width * 3
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BMP bmp1 = new BMP();

        try
        {
            bmp1.load("e:/1.bmp");
            System.out.println("Width:"+ bmp1.width + " length:" + bmp1.height);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your loaded image and its PixelReader you can construct a WritableImage which will provide you with a PixelWriter. That should be sufficient to work with the image. I would not extract that into an array.